# Show that $K=k(u)$ iff $u=\frac{ax+b}{cx+d}$ where $a,b,c,d \in k$ with $ad-bc \neq 0$

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

> Let $k$ be a field and let $K=k(x)$ be the rational function field in one variable over $k$. If $u\in K$, show that $K=k(u)$ iff $u=\frac{ax+b}{cx+d}$ where $a,b,c,d \in k$ with $ad-bc \neq 0$.

Now I have proved once that the automorphisms of the rational function field k(t) which fix k are
precisely the fractional linear transformations determined by $t \mapsto \frac {at+b}{ct+d}$ for $a, b, c, d ∈ k$, $ad−bc \neq 0$.

Now I am feeling that these two things are same but am unable to prove, can anyone help me to show the connection. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you really have it already. Certainly, if $u=(ax+b)/(cx+d)$, then $k(u)\subset k(x)$, right? Now use what you have already shown.

Comment: The connection is that if $k(u) = k(x)$, then define $\varphi : k(x) \to k(x)$ by $x\mapsto u$ and show that it extends to an automorphism of $k(x)$.